# How to add entries to Pulumi output for environment variables?

Tags: pulumi

I've created an `Output` for environment variables in Pulumi just like https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/aws-ts-airflow/index.ts#L61 but I need to add one entry to these env vars for one of the containers I'm spinning up.

I'd like to do something like when declaring a container similar to https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/aws-ts-airflow/index.ts#L79-L85

```
            "webserver": {
                image: awsx.ecs.Image.fromPath("webserver", "./airflow-container"),
                portMappings: [airflowControllerListener],
                environment: environment + {name: "ANOTHER_ENV", value: "value"},
                command: [ "webserver" ],
                memory: 128,
            },
```

I've tried playing around with `pulumi.all` (`pulumi.all([environment, {name: "FLASK_APP", value: "server/__init.py"}])`) and `environment.apply` but haven't been able to figure out how to contact to an `Output`.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to

```ts
const newEnvironment = environment.apply(env =>
    env.concat({ name: "ANOTHER_ENV", value: "value"}));

// ...

"webserver": {
    image: awsx.ecs.Image.fromPath("webserver", "./airflow-container"),
    portMappings: [airflowControllerListener],
    environment: newEnvironment,
    command: [ "webserver" ],
    memory: 128,
},
```

Comment: ah! I think actually we need to use `env.concat` instead of `env.push` but this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed! Fixed the answer.